# Facebook Like plugin reloading after drag or sort the plugin div using jquery

Tags: jquery, facebook

i'm using jquery drag drop for place Facebook plugin to a div
When i move the plugin it becomes reloading...
i'm not firing the fbml parse in drag/drop/sort events

this is the example

```
[Demo Link here](http://jsfiddle.net/aneeshsudhakaran/BSggz/embedded/result/)!
```

when i sort, the like button getting reload

Comment: what code do you got?? It would help a lot.

Comment: <div>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
</div>

when it load first time i will parse the div using fbml parse()

Comment: I was meaning your jquery code, and put it in your question

Comment: pls see this link http://jsfiddle.net/aneeshsudhakaran/BSggz/embedded/result/ -- this is the same code that i'm using

Comment: Yer I just realised that

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, but you'r not going to like it....

So the way jquery does the sortable thing, is it removes the element and makes a placeholder for it, and then when you release it, it adds it back into the sortable list, in place.

So as far as I know there is nothing you can do about it, unless you do it without sortable, and do it a different way.

So to see for your self look at the structure in the inspector (presuming you are using a good browser :-D) and drag the element around and you will see what it does.